# Prevent unneeded backend calls when using expressjs in a single page application

Tags: angular, express, angular-router

I have a single page application in Angular (10) with routing that uses a node backend.
I have added routing for my SPA in my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'page1',
    component: page1Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    component: page2Component,
  },
];
```

I also want to serve some files from the backend, some static content that i would prefer not to put in my dist folder, and some json responses from my backend code (api).
The server.js file for my node application looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/my-spa'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/users'));

app.get('/*', (req,res)=> res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get(/page1|page2/, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/my-spa/index.html');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port,() => console.log('running ...'));
```

This works great, but when I navigate in my SPA, say from page1 to page2, the index file is loaded again.
Is there a way to prevent calls for the index.html when I navigate through my SPA? I know I can achieve this by running my api on a different port or server, but I hope that is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misconfigured the anchor tags in your application.

SPA - Single Page Application states for apps that load `index.html` once, you don't need to setup routing on the backend side.

Once angular app is loaded and bootstrapped, the browser shouldn't reload the page. If it does, you probably used `<a href="/page">` instead of `<a routerLink="/page">`.